# syntax error near unexpected token near `('

Tags: bash

Command below does not run from script:

```sh
zcat *|cut -d"," -f1,2 | tr -d "\r" |
awk -F "," '{if (\$1 =="\"word\"" || \$1 =="\"word2\""){printf "\n%s",\$0}else{printf "%s",\$0}}' |
grep -i "resultCode>00000" | wc -l
```

Error:

```
./script.sh: command substitution: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script.sh: command substitution: line 8: `ssh -t user@ip 'cd "$(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)" && zcat *|cut -d"," -f1,2 | tr -d "\r" | awk -F "," '{if ($1 =="\"word\"" || $1 =="\"word2\""){printf "\n\%s",$0}else{printf "\%s",$0}}'| grep -i "resultCode>00000" | wc -l''
```

How should i fix syntax error near unexpected token?

Comment: This morass of syntax errors makes it very hard to guess what this should actually do. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: The command in the error message is completely a different one than the one you posted. There is no command substitution in there. Your SSH command line in the error message does contain one, and explains some of the quixotic quoting which is erroneous in isolation.

Comment: @PaulaDumitrache : You have to point out, what line 8 actually is; i.e. you have to show which command caused the error message to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ssh -t user@ip 'cd "$(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)" &&
    zcat *|cut -d"," -f1,2 | tr -d "\r" |
    awk -F "," '{if ($1 =="\"word\"" || $1 =="\"word2\""){
      printf "\n\%s",$0}else{printf "\%s",$0}}'|
    grep -i "resultCode>00000" | wc -l''
```

There's a mountain of syntax errors here.  First off, you can't nest single quotes like this: `''''`. That's two single-quoted empty strings next to each other, not single quotes inside single quotes.  In fact, there is no way to have single quotes inside single quotes. (It *is* possible to get them there by other means, e.g. by switching to double quotes.)

If you don't have any particular reason to run all of these commands remotely, the simplest fix is probably to just run the `zcat` in SSH, and have the rest of the pipeline run locally. If the output from `zcat` is massive, there could be good reasons to avoid sending it all over the SSH connection, but let's just figure out a way to fix this first.

```sh
ssh -t user@ip 'cd "$(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)" && zcat *' |
cut -d"," -f1,2 | tr -d "\r" |
awk -F "," '{if ($1 =="\"word\"" || $1 =="\"word2\""){
      printf "\n\%s",$0}else{printf "\%s",$0}}'|
grep -i "resultCode>00000" | wc -l
```

But of course, you can replace `grep | wc -l` with `grep -c`, and probably refactor all of the rest into your Awk script.

```sh
ssh -t user@ip 'cd "$(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)" && zcat *' |
awk -F "," '$1 ~ /^\"(word|word2)\"$/ { printf "\n%s,%s", $1, $2; next }
     { printf "%s,%s", $1, $2 }
 END { printf "\n" }' |
grep -ic "resultCode>0000"
```

The final `grep` can *probably* also be refactored into the Awk script, but without more knowledge of what your expected input looks like, I would have to guess too many things. (This already rests on some possibly incorrect assumptions.)

If you want to run all of this remotely, the second simplest fix is probably to pass the script as a here document to SSH.

```sh
ssh -t user@ip <<\:
cd "$(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)" &&
zcat * |
awk -F "," '$1 ~ /^\"(word|word2)\"$/ { printf "\n%s,%s", $1, $2; next }
     { printf "%s,%s", $1, $2 } END { printf "\n" }' |
grep -ic "resultCode>00000"
:
```

where again my refactoring of your Awk script may or may not be an oversimplification which doesn't do exactly what your original code did. (In particular, removing DOS carriage returns from the end of the line seems superfluous if you are only examining the first two fields of the input; but perhaps there can be lines which only have two fields, which need to have the carriage returns trimmed. That's easy in Awk as such; `sub(/\r/, "")`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Checking your code, it completely changes how i want to grep in a XML file with many fields.
 
Taking separately the commands, the part that gives error is the awk. I have preceded $ sign with backslash , 
but i can figure out what is wrong with this part: 

awk -F "," '{if (\$1 =="\"word\"" || \$1 =="\"word1\""){printf "\n%s",\$0}else{printf "%s",\$0}}'


This awk works ok in command line as below:

awk -F "," '{if ($1 =="\"word\"" || $1 =="\"word1\""){printf "\n%s",$0}else{printf "%s",$0}}'

Comment: You mean you really want literal double quotes around `word` and `word2`? Sure, that's easy to add back.

Comment: There should be no need to backslash-escape the dollar signs if you run the code locally. Forcing it to run over SSH causes the remote shell to perform another round of quote interpolation and backslash removal etc. That is one of the many reasons I want to dissuade you from doing that. Passing the script as a here document also fixes that.

Comment: The use of `(ls -td path/* | tail -n1)` to get the newest entry from `path` is a bit of a wart, but too lazy to try to fix that. There is no obvious and elegant solution to that which is also portable to multiple platforms; `stat` would be better but its features and formatting options are different on Linux and BSD.